# What is the best way to use Socket.io with Express.JS genereted project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

As I was new to Express I was wondering what could be the best way to install it with generator and use Socket.io in it.

For many of the tutorials they show ways to install socket.io but in a manually installed Express project.

Can any one suggest a better solution for this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate NodeJS (Express 4.x) new project by runing: `npm install express --save` and follow the instructions.
After what you'll be having different folders inside your Project directory:

- bin: where is located the www (basic configuration file for the project)
- public: where are stored /images, /javascritps and /stylesheets
- routes: where are stored routes files (index.js and users.js at the begining)
- views: where we find .html files to be used (index.html, layout.html and error.html at the begining)

and we also have 2 more files:

- app.js
- package.json

After this installation of course you'll need to run `npm install` to install the basic dependencies.

And for having socket.io in your project run `npm i -s socket.io`

With this installation in place let's then make the required changes to make Socket.io work in our project. The files to be changed are: ***/bin/www***, ***/views/layout.html***, ***/routes/users.js*** and ***app.js***

- in **/bin/www**

replace this line

```
var app = require('../app');
```

with this

```
var app = require('../app').app;
```

and replace this one

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
```

with this

```
var server = require('../app').server;
```

- in **/views/layout.html**

replace this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

with this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io('//localhost:3000');
      socket.on('socketToMe', function (data) {
          console.log(data);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- in **app.js**

just below this line

```
var app = express();
```

add this

```
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

and before this line

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
```

add this middleware

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.io = io;
    next();
});
```

All this is what is required and if well done you'll ready to go.

For testing purpose you can modify a little bit **/routes/users.js** like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.io.emit("socketToMe", "Users"); // This line was added to test Socket.io in action
    res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

and then run `npm start` browse to `http://localhost:3000/users`, you should see `Users` in the browser console.

THAT'S ALL THANKS!